# Loading cached images from disk in background thread in android

Tags: android, multithreading, caching

I have a listview in which images are loaded from the internet and then are cached on the disk. While scrolling, I'm trying to load images from the disk in a background thread using ExecutorService (since there will be multiple images while scrolling) - something like this:

```
executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
           // load images from the disk
           // reconnect with UI thread using handler
        }
}
```

However, the scrolling is not at all smooth and is very jerky - as if the UI thread is getting blocked somewhere. But when I comment this given code, then the scrolling is smooth. I'm unable to understand the flaw in my implementation.

EDIT: Just now I figured out that the problem is happening when I pass the message to the UI thread from the background thread. If I comment that part, the scrolling is smooth (but ofcourse the image is not displayed)

Comment: You can give a try to LazyList => https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Comment: Thanks Paresh,but I already have my implementation done, with only this mentioned issue. It would be really helpful if I could know the mistake in my give code.

Comment: That's great job you are doing.

Comment: @SaurabhVerma are you using a view holder to display images?.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: Yes, I'm using a ViewHolder and a Hashmap of max size 20 nd the disk as cache

Comment: The weired thing is that if I comment the whole code inside run() method, then the UI scrolling is smooth - I'm unable to understand how can a worker thread effect UI performance !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lazy Loading or Universal Image Loader

Lazy List is lazy loading of images from sdcard or fomr server using urls. It is like on demand loading images.

Images can be cached to local sd card or phone mmeory. Url is considered the key. If the key is present in sdcard display images from sd card else display image by downloading from server and cache the same to location of your choice. The cache limit can set. You can also choose your own location to cache images. Cache can also be cleared.

Instead of user waiting to download large images and then displaying lazy list loads images on demand. Since images area cached you can display images offline.

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList. Lazy List

In your getview

```
imageLoader.DisplayImage(imageurl, imageview); ImageLoader Display method

public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) //url and imageview as parameters
{
imageViews.put(imageView, url);
Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);   //get image from cache using url as key
if(bitmap!=null)         //if image exists
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);  //dispaly iamge
else   //downlaod image and dispaly. add to cache.
{
queuePhoto(url, imageView);
imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
}
}
```

An alternative to Lazy List is Universal Image Loader

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader.

It is based on Lazy List(works on same principle). But it has lot of other configurations. I would prefer to use Universal Image Loader coz it gives you more configuration options. You can display a error image if downlaod failed. Can display images with rounded corners. Can cache on disc or memory. Can compress image.

In your custom adapter constructor

```
 File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(a, "your folder");

// Get singletone instance of ImageLoader
imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
// Create configuration for ImageLoader (all options are optional)
 ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(a)
  // You can pass your own memory cache implementation
 .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // You can pass your own disc cache implementation
 .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
 .enableLogging()
 .build();
 // Initialize ImageLoader with created configuration. Do it once.
 imageLoader.init(config);
 options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
 .showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_id)//display stub image
 .cacheInMemory()
 .cacheOnDisc()
 .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
 .build();
```

In your getView()

```
ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageview); 
imageLoader.displayImage(imageurl, image,options);//provide imageurl, imageview and options
```

You can configure with other options to suit your needs.

Along with lazy loading/Universal Image Loader you can **view holder for smooth scrolling and performance**.

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html.